# What is "Post on Changes" or "Reflection" functionality?

Tags: gosu, pcf, guidewire

I am new to CC Guidewire. I didnt understand what post on change will do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "postOnChange" attribute on a PCF UI element can either be true or false.

If it is true then everytime that UI field is changed by a user; it will POST back to the server.

The server will then execute the code in corresponding UI elements "onChange" attribute.

These together basically allows you to add a piece of code that will fire when that UI field is been changed on screen by the user.

The reflection items can be used to use AJAX style updates to multiple fields on the basis of others. It is a bit more complex to use and understand.